# Changing Java Path

Tags: java, jdk

Why do I see both jdk 1.8 and jdk 11 in my java home?  How do I make it so jdk 11 is the only version that is used?

```
tacchino@tacchino-MS-7B79:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/app/lang/java/jdk1.8.0_64

tacchino@tacchino-MS-7B79:~$ echo $PATH
/app/lang/java/jdk1.8.0_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java:/snap/bin:/home/tacchino/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.7/bin
```

Comment: With "/app/lang/java/jdk1.8.0_64" what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: @N0rbert just wanted to make sure you saw my reply. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to check the contents of `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` files.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert - I checked profile.d and that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the contents of `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` files.